# Вывод изображений из бд

Tags: php, html, база-данных, изображения, phpmyadmin

Не выводятся изображения из бд. В таблице user есть элемент `Ppage`, в котором хранится информация в виде строки в которой записано id изображений  (пример: Ppage=1358, id первой фотографии равен 1 второй 3 и т.д.) с помощью `str_split` я раскладываю Ppage на массив, далее с помощью `foreach` перебираю этот массив в  `$value`, нахожу строку с id равному `$value`, использую `base64_encode` для фото из бд, беру из таблицы значение `text` и вывожу всё это. Ошибок никаких не возникает ,но изображение как и текст не выводятся.

```
<?php
  $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register');
  $cook = $_COOKIE['login'];
  $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login` = '$cook'");
  $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
  $Ppage = str_split($row['Ppage']);
  foreach ($Ppage as $value){  
    $dm = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `id`= '$value'");
    $show_img = base64_encode($dm['img']);
    $Ttext = $dm['text'];?>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?=$show_img ?>" alt="">
    <p><?=$Ttext ?></p> 
  <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Может не совсем понял, но что если у Вас будет хотя бы более 10-ти изображений и к примеру id одного будет 11, второго 23 и так далее и Ваш Ppage будет например `Ppage=112372` Вы тоже будете разбивать строку на массив?

Comment: @Simon Если будет более 10 изображений то условное id 23 будет разбито на 2 и 3. Я знаю это, просто в моём случае это не имеет значения.

Comment: Для `$dm` не хотите сделать `->fetch_assoc()` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon не помогло

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump` после выполнения запроса и посмотрите, что Вам вернулось из БД - скорее всего либо ничего, либо формат поля с изображением не тот который Вы ожидаете.